# SQL Total of addresses with null values in selected fields

Tags: sql, oracle, null, sum

This is a very small version of my database:

```
house_name   house_number   po_box
(null)                  1   (null)
Happy House             2    12345
Dunno                   4   (null)
```

I need to run a script that would show me the total of addresses contains NULL value in 'House_name' column together with NULL value 'po_box' column.
For this database it would be total=1, because there is only one address that does not store house_name and po_box either.
Thanks.

Comment: sql-server or oracle?

Comment: Do you really want a `SUM()` or are you looking for a `COUNT()`?

Comment: @Galma88 Sorry, Oracle

Comment: @Siyual You're right, I am looking for `COUNT()` actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this in SQL Server:

```
select sum(house_number)
from yourtable 
where house_name is null and po_box is null
```

(*The same query should work in Oracle as well*)

Comment: I was trying `sum(house_name)` instead of `sum(house_number)`, but it showed me `SUM=(null)`. Thank you :)